# Django - registering an Admin model view in one app from another app

Tags: django, class, admin

I'm slightly confused as how I'm meant to do this, partly because the documentation is translated a little poorly from Chinese, partly because I am just getting my head around class based views.

**EDIT:** I am using [xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin) (drop in replacement of django admin) instead of the built-in django admin site.

I have the following directory structure:

```
Project
    manage.py
    db.sqlite3
    /docs
    /static
    /templates
    /main_app
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py *
        wsgi.py
        /apps
            /xadmin
                adminx.py *
            /survey
                admin.py *
```

And the following URL mappings in main_app.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

import xadmin
xadmin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^survey/', include('survey.urls')),
    url(r'xadmin/', include(xadmin.site.urls)),
]
```

The survey.admin has it's classes, e.g.

```
class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'is_published', 'need_logged_user', 'template')
    list_filter = ('is_published', 'need_logged_user')
    inlines = [CategoryInline, QuestionInline]
    actions = [make_published]

admin.site.register(Survey, SurveyAdmin)
```

I know my Survey app's models are working properly, because when I check db.sql3, I can see my dummy entries in there. When I log into *127.0.0.1:8000/admin*, I can see that the SurveyAdmin view is registered and available.

When I log into *127.0.0.1:8000/xadmin* however, SurveyAdmin isn't registered.

From the [xadmin docs](http://xadmin.readthedocs.io/en/docs-chinese/site_api.html) I get that I have to register admin class views in xadmin.adminx. The admin class views I want to register already exist in survey.admin. I believe all I need to get this working is to move those views to xadmin.adminx - I really just want to check to make sure this is correct before I do so.

Comment: You should specify more clearly that you are using xadmin rather than the built-in admin site.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add this also in `urls.py`:

```
from xadmin.plugins import xversion
xversion.register_models()
```

It's in the [quickstart docs](http://xadmin.readthedocs.io/en/docs-chinese/quickstart.html)

Comment: That's just for reversion which is why I left it out, but I have just set it up to double check. I have "Reversion: Revisions" in my Admin panel now - but no Survey....

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. All I had to do was move the classes from survey.admin to xadmin.adminx and change the parameters slightly.

moved from **survey.admin**

```
class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'is_published', 'need_logged_user', 'template')
    list_filter = ('is_published', 'need_logged_user')

admin.site.register(Survey, SurveyAdmin)
```

to **xadmin.adminx**

```
class SurveyAdmin(object):
    list_display = ('name', 'is_published', 'need_logged_user', 'template')
    list_filter = ('is_published', 'need_logged_user')

xadmin.site.register(Survey, SurveyAdmin)
```

Makes sense as xadmin.adminx is meant to replace your usual admin.py (which survey.admin was extending previously)